# In the absence of a physical model, how can I use free software to visualize stereochemistry?

Tags: stereochemistry, software

In a different [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/136138/conversion-of-molecular-structure-into-fischer-projection-for-compounds-having-m?noredirect=1#comment269708_136138), the task was to turn a wedge-and-dash representation into a Fischer projection. This involved rotation of a fairly complex molecule - either as a physical model or a mental model - to orient each chiral carbon in preparation for drawing the Fischer projection. How can you use free software to visualize this process?

[image]

Comment: This might be useful if kept in meta since most of formatting tricks are kept there.. +1

Comment: There is a lot of free 3d molecular viewers - Maestro for academics, VMD, Pymol, Avogadro... Some of them have option to optimize/clear structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used Jmol to make the following animated GIF:

[image]

First I used [NCBI's Pubchem Sketcher](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/edit3/index.html) to get the SMILES code for the molecule: CC(C(C(C)F)(Br)F)O

Then, I loaded it into JSmol running [here](https://chemapps.stolaf.edu/jmol/jsmol/simple.htm) using the load molecule by name button.
Internally, this triggers the command

`load /*file*/"https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure/CC(C(C(C)F)(Br)F)O/file?format=sdf&get3d=true`

I fixed the stereochemistry by clicking on the carbons with incorrect chirality after issuing the command "set picking INVERTSTEREO". To rotate around the bonds, I used "rotate branch @3 @2 180 180" and "rotate branch @3 @4 180 180". Finally, I chose the viewing orientations, displayed the orientationwith "show moveto" and issued the resulting moveto commands before and after rotating around the single bonds.

A more elaborate example with glucose (4 chiral centers) can be found on [Proteopedia](http://proteopedia.org/wiki/index.php/Fischer_projection).